# Coding custom Screen Navigation into Lightswitch HTML

Tags: javascript, lightswitch-2013

I would like to have Button action event in LS HTML go slightly against the built-in navigation framework.

Specifically, to have LS navigate from one AddEditScreen to another AddEditScreen automatically, triggered by this Button event.

The trick is this - I need it to navigate to the AddEditScreen of the "next item up" in the Browse Screen List, without returning to the Browse Screen.

Example:

Select item 'ABC01' on a Browse Screen > Navigate to the AddEditScreen for 'ABC01' > edit 'ABC01' > when finished editing, trigger an event that will enable LS to navigate directly to the AddEditScreen for '**ABC02**' from the Browse Screen list.

I have an open mind about what that event could be. A Button...anything at all.

I have created a Button and chose 'Write my own method'.

Does this look even close to code that will work, or will LS need to get the value of 'ABC01' from a query of some type?

```
myapp.AddEditHoldingInventory.Method_execute = function (screen) {
// Write code here.
var navigateToNextScreen = function (Method) {

        return screen.getStrRqsNum().then(function (StrRqsNum) {
            if (!!StrRqsNum) {

                return myapp.applyChanges().then(function () {

                    var paramValue = (Number(StrRqsNum) += 1).toString();

                            return myapp.ShowAddEditHoldingInventory(id);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```

The code above is modified by me, and I am not a programmer or developer. It is snippets from pieces I have gathered and am trying to make sense of.

What the code is trying 'miserably' to achieve, is:

get the value of StrRqsNumber > save the edits made on the screen > add +1 to the value of StrRqsNumber > navigate to the AddEditSCreen of the record with the new value.

StrRqsNumber = a column with a value. It is unique and identifies an asset. This is most likely NOT the best way to achieve what I am trying to achieve, so I am here for advice. I don't have to use this as the parameter, as long as I can hit the 'next item up' from the list.

Thank you very much for any input. I will be SO stoked to get this behavior working.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by joshbooker. Here was the solution, which only needed minimal project specific tailoring...

"Question
Vote as helpful
0
Vote
What I want to achieve is this, for example:

Browse Screen > Select item 1 of 15 in the list > scan in the information we need on the AddEditScreen for item 1 > hit the 'trigger', and have LS automatically Save that edit, then navigate to the AddEditScreen of item 2 of 15 > and so on.

Here is a working solution for this:

```js
/// <reference path="~/GeneratedArtifacts/viewModel.js" />

myapp.BrowseHoldingInventories.selectNextStrRqsNum_execute = function (screen)
{///custom screen method to set selected item to next StrRqsNum
    //calc next num
    var nextNum = (Number(screen.HoldingInventories.selectedItem.StrRqsNum) + 1).toString();
    // iterate collection data to find the next item
    var nextItem = msls.iterate(screen.HoldingInventories.data)
                        .where(function (i)
                        {
                            return i.StrRqsNum == nextNum;
                        }).first();
    if (nextItem)
    {   //if found - select the item & return true
        screen.HoldingInventories.selectedItem = nextItem;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {   //not found - return false
        return false;
    };
};

myapp.BrowseHoldingInventories.TapMethod_execute = function (screen) {
    // tap method of list item on browse screen.

    //handy way to save/set scroll position
    var scrollTopPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

    //currently selected item
    var item = screen.HoldingInventories.selectedItem;

    //showAddEditScreen - pass item
           // beforeShown: setup binding on FieldB
            //afterClosed: if commit & select next then recurse

    myapp.showAddEditHoldingInventory(item, {
        beforeShown: function (addEditScreen)
        {//this executes before the screen is shown
            //find the trigger field
            var contentItem = addEditScreen.findContentItem("FieldB");
            if (contentItem)
            {   //databind to catch value change
                contentItem.dataBind(contentItem.bindingPath, function(newValue){
                    if (newValue && contentItem.oldValue && newValue != contentItem.oldValue)
                    {   //if change then commit - this triggers close of addEditScreen
                        myapp.commitChanges();
                    }
                    contentItem.oldValue = newValue;
                });

            }
        },
        afterClosed: function (addEditScreen, navigationAction)
        {//this executes after the screen is closed
            //scroll browse screen to where we left off
            $(window).scrollTop(scrollTopPosition);
            //if commit
            if (navigationAction == msls.NavigateBackAction.commit)
            {   //try to select next item in list
                if (myapp.BrowseHoldingInventories.selectNextStrRqsNum_execute(screen) == true)
                {   //next item selected then recurse
                    myapp.BrowseHoldingInventories.TapMethod_execute(screen);
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

"